# What does vue-cli-plugin-vuetify do?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs, vuetify-loader

I have a project using Vuetify, my project is not bootstrapped by `vue-cli`

After using Vuetify for months(in production), I've found out that I didn't install `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify`!

What does this plugin actually do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As many CLI plugins it contains `generator` to scaffold new Vuetify App - you can get overview what it does by looking at the [set of questions](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/blob/master/packages/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/prompts.js) it asks when executed
2. Second part is runtime (which for CLI plugin means when `serve` or `build` is executed) to [extend Webpack config](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/blob/master/packages/vue-cli-plugin-vuetify/index.js)

- activating `VuetifyLoaderPlugin` responsible for [treeshaking](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/)
- modifying `vue-loader`'s [transformAssetUrls config](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls)
- bootstrap [SASS variables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/)

Most of the things can be done manually (look for `Webpack install(ation)` on pages linked above), CLI plugin just make it easier for user (and that's the point of Vue CLI in general)

Answer (score 0):

A Vue CLI Plugin for scaffolding Vuetify application components, directives, mixins and views.

Comment: Not true, that's `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify-cli`